# Android Espresso vs Actionbar

Tags: android, testing, android-espresso

I have been trying to test an app that has a menu drawer using Espresso.

Now for the strangeness.

In the first test, I open the drawer and click on an item then proceed with the rest of the test.  That all works great.

When I add a second test that does the exact same thing, I get an exception.  It appears to be something related to content of the menu drawer but I am at a loss.

The exception is this:

```
com.google.android.apps.common.testing.ui.espresso.PerformException: Error performing 'single click' on view '(with id: is <2131099739> and with text: is "Events")'.
at com.google.android.apps.common.testing.ui.espresso.PerformException$Builder.build(PerformException.java:67)
at com.google.android.apps.common.testing.ui.espresso.base.DefaultFailureHandler.getUserFriendlyError(DefaultFailureHandler.java:57)
at com.google.android.apps.common.testing.ui.espresso.base.DefaultFailureHandler.handle(DefaultFailureHandler.java:40)
at com.google.android.apps.common.testing.ui.espresso.ViewInteraction.runSynchronouslyOnUiThread(ViewInteraction.java:146)
at com.google.android.apps.common.testing.ui.espresso.ViewInteraction.doPerform(ViewInteraction.java:77)
at com.google.android.apps.common.testing.ui.espresso.ViewInteraction.perform(ViewInteraction.java:69)
at com.xxx.app.events.StackOverflowExampleTest.selectMenu(StackOverflowExampleTest.java:83)
at com.xxx.app.events.StackOverflowExampleTest.setUp(StackOverflowExampleTest.java:72)
at android.test.AndroidTestRunner.runTest(AndroidTestRunner.java:192)
at android.test.AndroidTestRunner.runTest(AndroidTestRunner.java:177)
at android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner.onStart(InstrumentationTestRunner.java:555)
at com.google.android.apps.common.testing.testrunner.GoogleInstrumentationTestRunner.onStart(GoogleInstrumentationTestRunner.java:119)
at android.app.Instrumentation$InstrumentationThread.run(Instrumentation.java:1608)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Action will not be performed because the target view does not match one or more of the following constraints:
at least 90 percent of the view's area is displayed to the user.
Target view: "TextView{id=2131099739, res-name=menu_item_content, visibility=VISIBLE, width=432, height=112, has-focus=false, has-focusable=false, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=24.0, y=2.0, text=Events, input-type=0, ime-target=false}"
at com.google.android.apps.common.testing.ui.espresso.ViewInteraction$1.run(ViewInteraction.java:100)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:442)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4898)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1006)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:773)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

And here is the test class

```
public class StackOverflowExampleTest extends ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2<MainActivity_>
{
    public StackOverflowExampleTest()
    {
        super(MainActivity_.class);
    }

    /**
     * Basic check for content displayed
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public void testSanityCheck()
    {
        // check title is shown
        onView(allOf(withId(R.id.event_view_title), isDisplayed())).check(
                        matches(withText("Isaac Vladimir Sinead Stacey"))); //$NON-NLS-1$

        // check content is shown
        onView(allOf(withId(R.id.event_view_text), isDisplayed())).check(
                        matches(withText(startsWith("Arcu ipsumcurabitur. Aliquammauris sodalessed arcu.")))); //$NON-NLS-1$

        // check "more details" is shown
        onView(allOf(withId(R.id.event_view_link), isDisplayed()))
                        .check(matches(withText(R.string.events_button_text)));
    }

    /**
     * Basic check for content displayed
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public void testSanityCheck2()
    {
        // check title is shown
        onView(allOf(withId(R.id.event_view_title), isDisplayed())).check(
                        matches(withText("Isaac Vladimir Sinead Stacey"))); //$NON-NLS-1$

        // check content is shown
        onView(allOf(withId(R.id.event_view_text), isDisplayed())).check(
                        matches(withText(startsWith("Arcu ipsumcurabitur. Aliquammauris sodalessed arcu.")))); //$NON-NLS-1$

        // check "more details" is shown
        onView(allOf(withId(R.id.event_view_link), isDisplayed()))
                        .check(matches(withText(R.string.events_button_text)));
    }

    @Override
    protected void setUp() throws Exception
    {
        super.setUp();

        // start the activity
        this.getActivity();

        // show events fragment
        this.selectMenu(R.string.menu_item_events);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
    protected void selectMenu(final int menuItemResId)
    {
        // open the drawer
        onView(withId(android.R.id.home)).perform(click());

        // click the supplied menu item (aka list item)
        onView(allOf(withId(R.id.menu_item_content), withText(this.getActivity().getString(menuItemResId)))).perform(
                        click());

    }
}
```

Answer (score 15):

I had the same issue when the view you are going to operate on is not visible on  the screen or visible partially. So if you have problem with some view on screen - just scroll to it and then click:

```
onView(withId(is(R.id.button_login))).perform(
    scrollTo(), 
    click());
```

If you have this problem in drawer which has a list of items and you want to click at item which is not visible - use onData(...). But you have to show drawer before (see how to open drawer [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-test-kit-discuss/bmLQUlcI5U4)):

```
onData(is(instanceOf(com.your.package.SomeDrawerItem.class)))
    .inAdapterView(withId(R.id.drawer_listview))
    .atPosition(itemPositionInDrawer).perform(click());
```

Comment: I will +1 for this nice answer but unfortunately I still cant seem to explain why the same test run twice and the first time it's ok and the second run fails.  I always believed that the tests where independant of each other, this seems to imply otherwise which is scary.

Comment: I'm not pretty sure about this but try to move selectMenu(R.string.menu_item_events); inside your test methods.

Comment: I used this fix and it worked great but following .perform(click()); on some physical devices the softkeyboard opened thus covering the next buttons I wanted to press. I had to added Espresso.closeSoftKeyboard(); to solve this. Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like view in the drawer is not visible yet. You could maybe try to assert the visibility of the view before performing any action on it :

```
assertTrue(withEffectiveVisibility(Visibility.VISIBLE).matches(myView));
assertFalse(withEffectiveVisibility(Visibility.VISIBLE).matches(myView));
```

Comment: Thanks I was able to test the visbility of the view but how can I handle the exception. I mean, if the view is not visibility then how can I write the else code?

Comment: What do you want to assert exactly ?

Comment: I wanted to check the visibility of a view. In case the view is not visible or is set to View.Gone, this throws AssertionFailed Error. I have now handled the error.

Comment: What is getting to me is that it's the same test twice, the first run is ok and the second fails.  Tests are supposed to be independant and so this result baffles me.